# Moving class call using registry from module to Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to test some code initially written to be run in class module but I'm moving it to run in  Jupyter notebook.
The code uses class registry to create objects in "**init**.py" (see below code). I believe I copied all relevant classes , but still getting error message saying "object missing in the registry".
Is there away to fix the error or simply bypass the the class registry.

```
# ********* inside __init__.py ************
from basic.utils import METRIC_REGISTRY

__all__ = ['calculate_psnr', 'calculate2']


def calculate_metric(data, opt):
    
    opt = deepcopy(opt)
    metric_type = opt.pop('type')
    metric = METRIC_REGISTRY.get(metric_type)(**data, **opt)
    return metric
```

Registry class:

class Registry():

```
    def __init__(self, name):
        
        self._name = name
        self._obj_map = {}

    def _do_register(self, name, obj, suffix=None):
        if isinstance(suffix, str):
            name = name + '_' + suffix

        assert (name not in self._obj_map), (f"An object named '{name}' was already registered "
                                             f"in '{self._name}' registry!")
        self._obj_map[name] = obj

    def register(self, obj=None, suffix=None):
      
        if obj is None:
            # used as a decorator
            def deco(func_or_class):
                name = func_or_class.__name__
                self._do_register(name, func_or_class, suffix)
                return func_or_class

            return deco

        # used as a function call
        name = obj.__name__
        self._do_register(name, obj, suffix)

    def get(self, name, suffix='basicsr'):
        ret = self._obj_map.get(name)
        if ret is None:
            ret = self._obj_map.get(name + '_' + suffix)
            print(f'Name {name} is not found, use name: {name}_{suffix}!')
        if ret is None:
            raise KeyError(f"No object named '{name}' found in '{self._name}' registry!")
        return ret

    def __contains__(self, name):
        return name in self._obj_map

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._obj_map.items())

    def keys(self):
        return self._obj_map.keys()



LOSS_REGISTRY = Registry('loss')
METRIC_REGISTRY = Registry('metric')
```

impelmeantion:

```
@METRIC_REGISTRY.register()
def calculate_ssim(val, val2, **kwargs):
    # some implemantion
    return somevalue
```

call funcation:

```
calculate_metric(metric_data, opt_)
```

Error:

```
-> 2582         self.metric_results[name] += calculate_metric(metric_data, opt_)
   
   2584 if use_pbar:

Input In [53], in calculate_metric(data, opt)
     11 opt = deepcopy(opt)
     12 metric_type = opt.pop('type')
---> 13 metric = METRIC_REGISTRY.get(metric_type)(**data, **opt)
     14 return metric

Input In [54], in Registry.get(self, name, suffix)
   1870     print(f'Name {name} is not found, use name: {name}_{suffix}!')
   1871 if ret is None:
-> 1872     raise KeyError(f"No object named '{name}' found in '{self._name}' registry!")
   1873 return ret

KeyError: "No object named 'calculate_psnr' found in 'metric' registry!"
```